# Gson: read json file in /src folder and append object to it

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to read/write a file into the /src folder (I'm using Eclipse, it automatically generate src folder).
I have a dom object like this:

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private String surname;
... getters, setters and constructors here ...
}
```

in the /src folder, I need a "persons.json" file, where I want to add a new person, every time a new one is generated by a form (swing gui).
When I open the application, I want to load all the people in the file:

```
InputStream in = Person.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("scontrini_oggi.json");
String personString = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
Person[] persons = gson.fromJson(personString, Person.class);
```

First problem: it gives an error with a file like this:

```
{
    "name": "myname",
    "surname": "my surname"
},
{
    "name": "myname2",
    "surname": "mysurname 2"
}
```

It prints the String personString (so it actually reads the file), but when it tries to convert to Person object, there is a ClassCastException.
Then, the other problem is that if I have a Person object, I want to append it to the file, but I have no idea how to achieve this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, the JSON example file you are providing is wrong.

This is not a valid JSON file:

```
{
    "name": "myname",
    "surname": "my surname"
},
{
    "name": "myname2",
    "surname": "mysurname 2"
}
```

Those are two objects separated by a comma. If you want a *list* of objects then the JSON file must be like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "myname",
    "surname": "my surname"
  },
  {
    "name": "myname2",
    "surname": "mysurname 2"
  }
]
```

Then, as in the @Raman answer, you should ask for an array.

This a full working example.

```
package net.sargue.gson;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class SO36629514 {
  private class Person {
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Person{" + "name='" + name + '\'' +
              ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
              '}';
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "[\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "    \"name\": \"myname\",\n" +
            "    \"surname\": \"my surname\"\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "    \"name\": \"myname2\",\n" +
            "    \"surname\": \"mysurname 2\"\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "]";

    Person[] persons = new Gson().fromJson(json, Person[].class);
    System.out.println("persons = " + Arrays.toString(persons));
  }
}
```

And this is the execution result:

```
persons = [Person{name='myname', surname='my surname'}, Person{name='myname2', surname='mysurname 2'}]
```

Comment: Thank's, the first problems seems solved now. For the second problem? Is there a solution to append another person to the file?

Thank you!

Comment: Add the person to the array. Write the new array overwriting the file. If you need more information ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your code look like

`Person[] myTypes = gson.fromJson(personString, Person[].class);`

Comment: Thank you. I tried that way, but it only takes the first one, I don't know why.

Comment: If you have control over your json file, you can wrap that '[' and ']', to make it an array.

file content should be like -
[
//old file content
]